# GetFileLineNumber() returns 0, even though I'm using a debug build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stack-frame

I'm using VS2010 to develop my project. In my codebase, I use the stackframe's `GetFileLineNumber()` function. At runtime, however, it always returns `0`. This happens even though I am running a debug build. I have also confirmed that the generated pdb file exists alongside the generated executable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 31):

Aha! I found the information squirreled away at the bottom of MS' reference post:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.getfilelinenumber(v=vs.80).aspx

Turns out you have to construct your StackTrace instance like so:

```
st = new StackTrace(true);
```

The `true` gets you file & line info.